# Python module functioning properly in command prompt but not in script

Tags: python

I've installed the win32gui module into python 2.7.

I'm trying to run the following line:

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
print GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
```

When run in a python terminal, it returns the active window. When building this into the script I'm working on (which is part of a Twitch Chat Bot), I immediately am notified that win32gui doesn't exist.

What can I do to make it notice the module?

Comment: Make sure you're running your script on `python2`

Comment: The only python ive got installed on my system is 2.7, and everything is running that.